# Ensure exact literal matches have priority over regex when using Nginx map module

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to setup a number of redirects, some based on a particular regex rule and some based on a fixed list of literal values.

My config looks like so:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 256;
map $request_uri $new_uri {
  include /etc/nginx/redirect/blogs.map;
  "~^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)" /blog/$1;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;

    server_name _;

    absolute_redirect off;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    charset utf-8;

    if ($new_uri) {
      return 301 $new_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Where the included file has items such as:

```
/2002/03/12/slug-of-blog /blog;
```

As it is above, this config doesn't work at all. It doesn't seem to map any of the values.

Whereas, originally I had the regex as a location block:

```
    location ~ "^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)" {
        return 301 /blog/$1;
    }
```

In this instance both the regex and the mapped URI's worked fine in isolation, however, the regex would take priority over an exact match from the included file.

To give an example:

`/2002/03/12/slug-of-blog` would match the regex even when I had a mapped literal value inside `/etc/nginx/redirect/blogs.map;` e.g.:

```
/2002/03/12/slug-of-blog /something-else;
```

I would have expected `/2002/03/12/slug-of-blog` to redirect to `/something-else` instead it redirected to `/blog/slug-of-blog`.

Therefore, I tried the former method (adding it inside the map) which the docs seemed to imply would be possible with the version of Nginx I'm running but I've had no such luck.

Comment: did you try to move the literal match for testing directly to your config, instead of the include file?
did you try to swap the order of include and regex in the config?

Comment: The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) confirms that an exact value takes precedence over a regular expression value irrespective of inclusion order. Check the access log for the exact URL being received by the server. `$request_uri` is url-encoded and also includes the query string, either of which may prevent the string value from matching.

Comment: Ok so with further testing it seems like the above is working. I believe I was being confused by a combination of caching and trailing slashes that weren't mapping to the exact values I had in the list. Changing the listed exact values to `~^/2002/03/12/slug-of-blog/? /something-else/;` handled the presence or absence of trailing slashes. Testing everything in an incognito session and all is well.

Comment: Oh yes, permanent redirects (301) are cached in the browser.